# POST javascript variable with php form submission

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps

I am using Goole Maps and want to include 2 javascript variables with a form post (longitude and latitute of the marker).  Here's what I have:

```
 function saveData() {
      var name = escape(document.getElementById("name").value);
      var address = escape(document.getElementById("address").value);
      var type = document.getElementById("type").value;
      var latlng = marker.getLatLng();
      var lat = latlng.lat();
      var lng = latlng.lng();
```

I need to include "var lat" and "var lng" with an existing form post.

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="catchprocess.php">
```

Thanks for any help you con provide!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can assign these lattitude and longitude inside `hidden field` in a form

```
  var lat = latlng.lat();
      var lng = latlng.lng();
    document.getElementById("t1").value=lat;
    document.getElementById("t2").value=lng;

   <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="catchprocess.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="lat" id="t1">
        <input type="hidden" name="long" id="t2">
//form end
```

In `catchprocess.php`,you can access thes lat,long through

```
$_POST['lat'] and $_POST['long']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var inp = document.createElement('input');
inp.setAttribute('type', 'text'); // or hidden
inp.setAttribute('name', 'lat');
inp.setAttribute('value', lat);

document.getElementById("form1").appendChild(inp)
```